# Get only inner text from webelemnt

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver

I want to get only innerText from a webelement. I want to get only "Name" from the anchor tag.I have access to webdriver element associated with  tag in below example(anchorElement).
I tried anchorElement.getText() and anchorElement.getAttribute("innerText"). Both return me "Name, sort Z to A". What should I do here ?

```
<a id="am-accessible-userName" href="javascript:void(0);" class="selected">
Name 
<span class="util accessible-text">, sort Z to A</span> 
<span class="jpui iconwrap sortIcon" id="undefined" tabindex="-1"> 
<span class="util accessible-text" id="accessible-"></span> 
<i class="jpui angleup util print-hide icon" id="icon-undefined" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
</a>
```

Comment: you can split the string at (,). here the is java code to do the same.
String fullText=anchorElement.getText();
fullText=fullText.split(",")[0];

now fullText will contains the value "Name".

Comment: That may not the be possible every time. We need a generic solution.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A bit of Javascript can pick out just the child text node:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = ...
WebElement anchorElement = driver.findElement(By.id("am-accessible-userName"));
String rawText = (String) driver.executeScript(
    "return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;", 
    anchorElement);
```

So `anchorElement` is passed into the Javascript as `arguments[0]` there.

Clearly `childNodes[0]` is assuming where the text node is.  If that's not safe, you could iterate the childNodes too, perhaps checking for `childNode.nodeName === "#text"`

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot. This should help me..Will accept it once I try it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* the desired element is a *Text Node* and also the *First Child Node* of the `<a>` tag. So to extract the text **Name** you can use the following code block :

- *Java Binding Art* :

  ```
  WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='selected' and @id='am-accessible-userName']"));
  String myText = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", myElement);
  System.out.println(myText);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The text alone could be obtained by using proper javascript code to iterate through child nodes of a given weblement and then returning text if the current node is a text node.
Note: A trimmed value of node text will be returned.

```
public String getInnerText(WebDriver e, String xpathStr){
WebElement ele = e.findElement(By.xpath(xpathStr));
        return ((String) ((JavascriptExecutor) e).executeScript("var children = arguments[0].childNodes;\n" +
                "for(child in children){\n" +
                "   if(children[child].nodeName === \"#text\"){" +
                "  return children[child].nodeValue };\n" +
                "}" , ele )).trim(); 
}
```